# How to compare trigonometric functions in R?

Tags: r, function

How can I show that these 2 functions are equal?

```
a<-function(x) sec^2(x)
b<-function(x) 1+tan^2(x)
```

I tried using `identical` but it’s showing false.

```
identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use package [Ryacas](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/index.html) for that.

Comment: R does not have a `sec` function in its default packages. Where does that come from?

Comment: (1) Do you have a `sec` function? I don't, so I have to define it: `sec <- function(x) 1/sin(x)` or just use `1/sin(x)` directly. (2) In R, the way to write your first function is `sec(x)^2`, not `sec^2(x)`. (3) `identical(a,b)` for you is testing equality of two *functions*, you need to test the functions' *results*.

Comment: @r2evans: please, notice that `sec(x) = 1 / cos(x)`.

Comment: Yup, you're right, it was a quick drive-by typing, intended to get the point across. The comment otherwise stands.

Answer (score 5):

Using just base R, you can take some range of values for x, compute values for these values for both functions and see if they are equal.

```
a <- function(x) (1/cos(x))^2

b <- function(x) 1 + tan(x)^2

x <- seq(from = -2 * pi, to = 2*pi, length.out = 1e4)

all.equal(a(x), b(x))
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) installed (that is free), you can use `rim`:

```r
library(rim)
#> Maxima successfully registered as knitr engine!

maxima.get("trigsimp(1+(tan(x))^2 - (sec(x))^2);")
#> (%o1) 0
```